# queue not producing correct output

Tags: java, regex, stack, queue

Test Program:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "1 + 4";
        new MyClass(str);
    }
}
```

Problem code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(String str)
    {
        Stack<String> operators = new Stack<String>();
        Queue<String> output = new LinkedList<String>();
        String[] tokens = str.split("\\s");
        StringBuilder postFixStr = new StringBuilder();
        final String isDigit = "[0-9]";
        final String isOperator = "[(^/*+\\-)]";

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
            if (tokens[i].matches(isDigit))
            {
                output.offer(tokens[i]);
            }
            else if (tokens[i].matches(isOperator))
            {
                operators.push(tokens[i]);
            }
        }

        output.offer(operators.pop());

        for (int j = 0; j < output.size(); j++)
        {
            postFixStr.append(output.poll());
        }

        System.out.print(postFixStr.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
14
```

Output should be:

```
14+
```

If I change:

```
final String isDigit = "[0-9]";
```

To:

```
final String isDigit = "";
```

Output:

```
+
```

I can not get both numbers and symbols to store in the queue. Only one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually the `for` loop control.

Replace this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < output.size(); j++)
{
    postFixStr.append(output.poll());
}
```

for this:

```
while (output.size() > 0)
{
    postFixStr.append(output.poll());
}
```

and it will work like a charm.

**Explanation**

As expression `j < output.size()` is evaluated before each iteration and `output` list has one element removed each time the loop iterates 2 times and not 3 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in using ".size()" in the for loop to determine the number of elements in output.  Because an element is removed from output every iteration of the loop from calling poll(), the loop exits early.

To resolve this problem, store the size in a separate variable before running the loop.

Like this:

```
int size = output.size();
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
  postFixStr.append(output.poll());
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.